# Tensorflow namescope

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

What's the purpose of doing stuff like

```
 with tf.name_scope('Layer1') as n1:
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((50*50, 120), mean=0, stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([120]))
    o = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, w)+b)
```

I would guess it is for readability, and so that you can reuse variable names outside the code block (name_scope), and that it does not have more profound meaningful consequences.

When would I use this, what are good scenarios for it? To tensorflow practitioners use name_score a lot?

Also, can somebody please give me an example of how `sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name()` works in the context of `name_scope`?

Answer (score 1):

So it namescope can be used for readability in code of course. But it also works for getting the name's of the tensors saved in your graph. This is very useful for example when you are  trying to represent data in Tensorboard or getting a tensor by name!

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on the part about getting the names of the tensors? Maybe a code example?

Comment: For sure!
I had this graph which was a retrained inception model: when I wanted to get the tensor that had the operation that I wanted to do inference, to grab the tensor from the graph you use:
    tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('op_to_restore:0')

Comment: Ok, but in your example, what is the name of the name_scope, and what is the name of the actual variable inside it?

Comment: In my example it's just a demo gor grabbing tensors by name, when you use namescopes it means that all the tensors inside the namescope will have a parent named in that tensor. Suppose u have two layers and each layer has a namescope: layer1 and layer2, now you name the tensors inside weights and bias for example, since you are suing scopes the tensors' names will be like: layer1/weights, layer1/bias, layer2/weights, layer2/bias. I hope I made myself clear! :)

Comment: Sorry, not quite there yet. So let's say you have those 2 layers with the variables, then how can you use sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(...), with those specific layer names and variable names?

Comment: No problem! So it will be as easy as: `my_weights_layer_1 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer1/weights')`

Answer (score 0):

Namescope is used to divide the operations into their scopes for easy readability and extract-ability. For e.g., you have ResNet with different residual layers, or Inception with different Inception layers, you can group these layers using namescope e.g. ResLayer1, ResLayer2 or InceptionLayer1, InceptionLayer2, creating the same layer in different scopes.

Also when you load your models, you can extract the operations and tensors easily by populating the graph nodes and then finding the relevant nodes per layer as they are now correctly labelled. For e.g. you train the model, and send me the trained '.pb' model file to deploy, I have no idea what the Input or Output Nodes are. But I can populate your graph and look at the names and easily run the graph if you have correctly labelled using Namescope. Also I can access different output layers with that.

Another thing that @Ignacio Peletier mentioned, when using TensorBoard, the visualized graph is grouped according to namescope allowing easy visibility of the graph.

Comment: Can you please answer my question from above? Let's say you have those 2 layers with the variables, then how can you use sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(...), with those specific layer names and variable names? I.e. can you give me concrete example with a name_scope and variable name, and how would you apply get_tensor_by_name on it?

Comment: So for example each layer under a neural network is created and each layer has it's activation as ReLU. Now if you want to access the activation for each layer with number n, you could access it as:

`act = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("layer1/activation")`